# Is it possible to GroupBy a set of values using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, hashset

I know how it's possible to use anonymous types to group by a fixed list of values.  What I want to do is group by an actual set of values.

For example, the result of this expression is 2.

```
new List<HashSet<int>> {
    new HashSet<int> { 4 },
    new HashSet<int> { 4 }
}.GroupBy (x => x).Count()
```

I'm looking for a way to put those sets in the same group so that the result would be 1.  In python, this would be accomplished using `frozenset`.

What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: You don't want to group. You need to use SelectMany

Comment: So you 'd want the result of this expression to be 1?

Comment: Are you wanting to combine elements within the hashsets to make a single hashset, or do you want to combine all similar hashsets? The distinction isn't very clear here. If you want to combine all hashsets into a single, then use `SelectMany` as @AmiramKorach pointed out. If you want to group by the hashset itself, then you need to provide an `IEqualityComparer` implementation for Hashset<T>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334

Comment: @AmiramKorach: I was not trying to calculate a union, I was trying to group a set of objects by a hashset-based key.  Thanks all for the input.  `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer` is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the static [`HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475.aspx) method for this purpose.

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer> An
>   IEqualityComparer object that can be used for deep equality testing of
>   the HashSet object.

```
new List<HashSet<int>> {
    new HashSet<int> { 4 },
    new HashSet<int> { 4 }
}.GroupBy (x => x, HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer())
```

Comment: +1 because there's something new to learn every day... :) I wonder why they thought it was worth it to have this built-in though.

Answer (score 3):

(I am assuming that you want to group both sets as "equal" -- the question is not terribly clear)

As is often the case with LINQ, the scaffolding to achieve this already exists and what needs to be done is to supply a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the appropriate method. In this instance this means using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx).

Here's a generic `IEqualityComparer<ISet<T>>` that declares two sets equal if their intersection is the same set as both of them:

```
class SetComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<ISet<T>> {
    public bool Equals(ISet<T> lhs, ISet<T> rhs) {
        // null checks omitted
        return lhs.SetEquals(rhs);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ISet<T> set) {
        // Not the best choice for a hash function in general,
        // but in this case it's just fine.
        return set.Count;
    }
}
```

And here's how you would group both sets under the same umbrella:

```
new List<HashSet<int>> {
    new HashSet<int> { 4 },
    new HashSet<int> { 4 }
}.GroupBy (x => x, new SetComparer<int>()).Count();
```

Comment: Downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment. Thank you.

Comment: The Equals method of the comparer, as it stands, isn't correct. From the `Except` docs: "This method returns those elements in first that do not appear in second. It does **not** also return those elements in second that do not appear in first." I would use `ISet<T>.SetEquals` instead.

Comment: @Ani: Oops. Thanks for the heads-up, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=new HashSet<int> { 4 }.Union(new HashSet<int> { 4 }).Count();
```

Comment: This just counts the number of values that two sets have in common.  It might be the basis of something that could be used, but my question was about grouping elements by a set.